# how to put a link to the php set message

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm quite new in php and I'm editing code in the cake php.

I would like to add a link to the help page after a error message:

existing code:

```
if (count($results) > 0) {
  $this->set("message", "Sorry, that data already exists.");          
  return;
}
```

something like this:

```
if (count($results) > 0) {
  $this->set("message", "Sorry, that data already exists.") <a href="http://www.example.com/">;          
  return;
}
```

should I use echo within a php code - it just does not work for me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use this code

```
if (count($results) > 0) {
  $this->set("message", "Sorry, that data already exists. <a href=\"http://www.example.com/\">Need help?</a>");          
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->set("message", 'Sorry, that data already exists.<a href="http://www.example.com/">');
```

Doing this will get the anchor in as part of the string, and if you need to echo it, it should be generated as HTML.

Answer (score 0):

it's simply:

```
if (count($results) > 0) {
    $this->set("message", 'Sorry, that data already exists. <a href="http://www.example.com/">');
    return;
}
```

Better use single quotes `'` and you don't need to escape `"` in tags attributes.

Or store link in variable:

```
if (count($results) > 0) {
    $link = '<a href="http://www.example.com/">';
    $this->set("message", "Sorry, that data already exists. $link");
    return;
}
```